# Using loop for data formatting in R

Tags: r, loops, zoo

I want to format lot's of df's in the same way - is it possible to write a loop? Let's call them df1, df2, df3,...

```
df1$timestamp<-as.POSIXct(df1$timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df1.zoo<-zoo(df1[,-1],df1[,1])
```

Tried:

```
x<-list(df1,df2,df3)
lapply(x, x$timestamp<-as.POSIXct(x$timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Getting the warning don't know how to apply the function....
Thanks!

Comment: Put the data.frames in a list and use `lapply`. That's the R way. It's extremely rare that you actually need a `while` loop in R.

Comment: Your *I found* section seems totally irrelevant to the question. Unless `work.on.gene(i)` does something with `dfi`?

Comment: Okay thats why it didn't work;-) I just thougt because of the loop - in general with the df1 - df3 and the formating stuff, how to deal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `lapply` function needs to be passed a function, not an expression.  Try:

```
x <- list(df1, df2, df3)
x2 <- lapply(x, function(y) {
  y$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(y$timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  y
} )
```

I changed the function argument to `y` so that it would not be confused with the list `x`.  This modifies the current df and returns it, `lapply` then collects the modified data frames into a new list (which I saved in `x2` but you could save back into `x`.

If you want to edit the data frames in place then a macro will probably work better, see the `defmacro` function in the gtools package and read the article referenced on its help page.